# using quotes inside innerHTML not working

Tags: javascript, html-lists, innerhtml

I am trying to use JavaScript to have a dynamic list, and I need to use a lot of of quotes to make the `<li>` line work as it should, but I cannot get innerHTML to output the correct syntax to the html doc.

here is my JS:

```
function settabnumber() {
    alert("set tab number function called");
    var settabcount = 3;
    var menucode;
    var i=0;
    for(basetabcount = 0; basetabcount < settabcount; basetabcount++){
    i++;
    menucode = menucode + "<li><a href=\"#tabs-" + i + "\">" + tabnames[i] +    "</a></li>";
    }
    document.getElementById("eetabmenu").innerHTML = menucode;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Try using single quotes (`'`) inside of your double quotes

Comment: Do your tabnames contain quotes ?

Comment: See the comment thread w/ Steven Petryk. I managed to get the correct string out but unfortunately my problem was jQuery UI. I managed to pass the parameters to jQuery UI using document.write instead of innerhtml.

Answer (score 1):

Try...

```
menucode = menucode + '<li><a href="#tabs-' + i + '">' + tabnames[i] + '</a></li>';
```

Always use single quotes to hold HTML strings so you can then freely use the obligatory double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

I made a JSFiddle attempting to reproduce your issue, but it wasn't occurring: https://jsfiddle.net/qf19wvr0/

Either way, as the other commenters said, you should use single quotes. OR, if you're working in an ES6 environment (using a transpiler like Babel), you can use template strings:

```
menucode += `<li><a href="#tabs-${i}">${tabnames[i]}</a></li>`
```

Which makes your snippet a lot more readable.

### However:

If you're doing complex enough work that you're looping over a collection and building up DOM nodes from strings, you may want to consider using some kind of templating system (like Handlebars, Mustache, React, or anything of the sort) to abstract some of your view creation logic. Having HTML strings in your JavaScript is a pretty big code smell and likely means you're mixing view logic with business logic.

Comment: Cheers - I think this might show what i'm trying to do:

https://jsbin.com/yisaquvibe/edit?html,output

The alert i create seems to show that the code is being created as it should be, however it does not seem to replace the tab menu as i want it to, instead it completely breaks it :(

Comment: Ah, I see. jQuery UI is adding special classes to your tabs _after_ the page loads. Just so you can see, try getting rid of your `.innerHTML =` line and right click on a tab, then click "Inspect element...". You can see that the HTML has been greatly changed by jQuery UI.

Comment: I understand. Thanks. What is my best way to use my function to pass the parameters to JQuery? use document.write instead?

Answer (score 0):

Use single quotes `'` inside of your double quotes, or viseversa

```
menucode = menucode + '<li><a href="#tabs-' + i + '">' + tabnames[i] + '</a></li>';
```

OR

```
menucode = menucode + "<li><a href='#tabs-" + i + "'>" + tabnames[i] + "</a></li>";
```

The first one is preferred